# How to use same Laravel Resource for different API response

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

i want to make two different functions on resource so that i can get a two different response .i.e i want the resource to return data without image and with image.

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'area_code' => $this->area_code
        ];
    }


    public function toArrayWithImages($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'area_code' => $this->area_code,
            'image' => $this->image
        ];
    }
```

this is what i tried but dont know how to point to the second function 'toArrayWithImages' . can someone explain me this ?
This is my controller ..

```
  public function getAllBusinessAreas()
    {
        try {
            $areas = Area::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
            return BusinessAreaResource::collection($areas);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return sendErrorResponse('Error fetching Business Areas', true, 500);
        }
    }
```

what it does is  by default it hits the toArray function i want to be specific which function to hit from controller. is it possible to do it ?

Comment: How will you know when to call `toArrayWithImages` method and when to follow the default pattern?

Comment: @Pusparaj thats what i want to be specific from controller but i am not sure how i can achieve this .

Comment: The question is not how to call different methods, but when to call. How will you determine which method to call after accepting a request?

Comment: Isn't it possible to just create two different resources for one model? That is kind of how Laravel designed the logic behind resources. 2 different presentations of the data of the same model means 2 different resource classes.

Comment: @MarkWalet thats what i came with too . i made two different resource for it and i call/point the resource which i want from controller.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what i am doing is adding an additional parameter to your request, **you can use a flash session variable as well if it is not possible to attach extra params to your request**, to filter weather it goes to the function which returns image or data without image.

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        if($request->with_image)
        {
           this::toArrayWithImages($request->except('with_image'));
        }
        else
        {
          this::toArrayWithoutImages($request->except('with_image'));
        }
   }


    public function toArrayWithoutImages($request)
    {
         return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'area_code' => $this->area_code
        ];
    }
    public function toArrayWithImages($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'area_code' => $this->area_code,
            'image' => $this->image
        ];
    }
```

Comment: if adding a parameter to the $request is not an option then use flash session to pass the data between pages/ function or classes